# Deploy github build from codeship to amazon EC2 through CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, codeship, aws-code-deploy

I'm getting an headache trying to use codedeploy with codeship, and

[Codeship documentation](https://codeship.com/documentation/continuous-deployment/deployment-to-aws-codedeploy/) is not very clear.
I have a sample code building well from codeship.

I have:

1. Instance of EC2 Server
2. CodeDeploy App with a deployment group: TestDeploymentGroup
   this group is relationed to a EC2 Server and with arn:aws:iam::514211081162:role/CodeDeploy
3. User with Access Key ID and Secret Access Key:

4- S3 Bucket with policy

```
 {
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::514211081162:role/CodeDeploy"
        },
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myapp/*"
    }
]
}
```

IAM Policies:

CodeDeployPolicy

arn:aws:iam::514211081162:policy/CodeDeployPolicy

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "codedeploy:RegisterApplicationRevision",
            "codedeploy:GetApplicationRevision"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "codedeploy:CreateDeployment",
            "codedeploy:GetDeployment"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "codedeploy:GetDeploymentConfig"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

This Policy has an attached entity: Role: CodeDeploy

arn:aws:iam::514211081162:role/CodeDeploy

arn:aws:iam::514211081162:instance-profile/CodeDeploy

The Role CodeDeploy has CodeDeployPolicy (defined up here) attached.
He has a Trust RelationShip

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
  "Sid": "",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "Service": [
      "codedeploy.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
      "codedeploy.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
    ]
  },
  "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
}
]
}
```

When I try to deploy, I get:

```
upload failed: ../../../../../../tmp/AWSCODEDEPLOY_deployment_8dbb2cbc72a5db1e2e15368cbe97e0b5fcdf987e.zip to s3://aws-codedeploy-us-west-2/myapp/AWSCODEDEPLOY_deployment_8dbb2cbc72a5db1e2e15368cbe97e0b5fcdf987e.zip
A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the    CreateMultipartUpload operation: Access Denied
```

I understand it is a permission problem, but honestly, it is too much parameters for me, and I am completly lost...

Comment: I'd try working through the CodeDeplyo wolkthrough first and then try to hook up CodeShip to be able to do some of those actions for you. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-walkthrough.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that destination bucket is right?

I find it hard to believe that `s3://aws-codedeploy-us-west-2/` (from the error) is yours. Nor `s3://myapp` (from the bucket policy), although I suppose that could be your example name.

Comment: Do you know where should I see what is my s3 url?

Comment: You need to create an s3 bucket - you must have already, otherwise where are you putting that bucket policy? `myapp` should be changed to your actual bucket name.

Comment: yes, I have a s3 bucket, but where should I see his url?